# Do I need to destroy singleton instance in my case?

Tags: c++, singleton, singleton-type

If the process is terminated after I use singleton instance like below.
Is there memory leak is exist?

1. If yes, How can I fix the problem?
2. Do I need to add "destroyInstance" member function?
3. If yes, when multi thread is already refer to the singleton instance,
   how can I assure multi thread safety?
   (Do I need to add reference count?)

I wonder that If I need to consider all of them, singleton pattern seems to very complex.

```
#include <mutex>

class Singleton 
{
    static Singleton *singletonInstance;
    Singleton() {}
    static std::mutex m_;

  public:

    static Singleton* getSingletonInstance()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        if(singletonInstance == nullptr)
        {
            singletonInstance = new Singleton();
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read about the *Meyers singleton*, as that will solve both the memory leak problem, as well as any thread synchronization without a lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need manual memory management for a singleton. Here's your example with `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

class Singleton 
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> singletonInstance;
    Singleton() {}
    static std::mutex m_;

  public:

    static Singleton* getSingletonInstance()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
        if (!singletonInstance)
        {
            singletonInstance = std::make_unique<Singleton>();
        }
        return singletonInstance.get();
    }
};
```

The `std::unique_ptr` destructor will be called when the process ends normally. Also, there is no need to synchonize destructor.

But even better, you should use Scott Meyer's singleton:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& getSingletonInstance() {
        static Singleton instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};
```

The example above is thread safe, even though no explicit lock is used.

---

For you Q3, even though the member function `getSingletonInstance` might be thread safe, usage of the singleton might not. Shared mutable state is inherently thread unsafe.

Comment: @Hercoa happy to help! consider accepting the answer if you found it useful

Comment: This doesn't work when an object with static storage duration (typically a global object) makes the first call to `getSingletonInstance()`, stashes away the returned pointer, and attempts to use that pointer in its destructor. The singleton's destructor runs before that object's destructor, so the object has a stale pointer. If I remember correctly, that's one of the problems solved by the Meyer's singleton, mentioned in one of the comments. It re-allocates the singleton when that happens.

Comment: @PeteBecker this is quite an unusual situation. Also I would be extremely surprised if my singleton would be reallocated in a destructor call, and surprising code is bad. Using other global object in the destructor of another global object is calling for trouble. And it only happens to be re-allocated in the case where you use the get function in the destructor. Usually with singletons you want to call the getter the fewest time possible, and pass it around like a normal object. It reduces the coupling and helps refactor.

Comment: If return &instance, return param is "static Singleton*" getSingletonInstance
Is it right?

Comment: @Hercoa Yes. I only changed it for a reference to make a simpler solution.